# Retrieve value from firebase; type is unknown

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase structure looks like this.

[Firebase pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUdHX.png)

I have two types of Users. When getting my snapshot, how can I instantiate my object based on the type stored in firebase. My code is below

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
   DatabaseReference databaseReference;
   FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

     if(firebaseUser != null){
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("User").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              //HOW CAN I FIX THIS TO BE THE CORRECT USER TYPE
              User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
              Intent intent = null;
              if(user != null){
                 //IF USER IS TYPE 1, CREATE USER OF TYPE 1 AND ADD STUFF TO MY INTENT
                 //IF USER IS TYPE 2, CREATE USER OF TYPE 2 AND ADD STUFF TO MY INTENT
                 finish();
                 startActivity (intent);
              }
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can just check the value of your node `userTypeId` from database and do what you want.

What I am saying, looks something like this in code:

```java
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(user != null){

                 if(dataSnapshot.child("userTypeId").getValue(String.class).equals(0))
                        // user type 1
                 else 
                       // user type 2

                finish();
                startActivity (intent);
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }


        });
```

Comment: No worries @Drogba, consider marking the answer as correct by clicking on tick mark looking V type button next to the answer, this helps future readers of the question and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)